# ReportLab numbering with nested bullet points

Tags: python, django-views, reportlab

I'm struggeling with ReportLab which I would like to use to generate a PDF as a request from Django from a view.

I try to get a numbered list with bullet points in between like that

1. Text1-blabla

   - Bullet-blabla
   - Bullet-blabla
2. Text2 blabla

But what I receive is:

1. Text1-blabla
2. - Bullet-blabla
   - Bullet-blabla
3. Text2 blabla

How can I suppres the "2." infront of the bullets or how can I skip it for that region?

This is my code

```
lf = ListFlowable([ ListItem(Paragraph(text1, styles["Normal"])), 
        ListFlowable([ListItem(Paragraph(text1a, styles["Normal"])), 
                    ListItem(Paragraph(text1b, styles["Normal"])),
                    ListItem(Paragraph(text1c, styles["Normal"])),
                    ListItem(Paragraph(text1d, styles["Normal"])),
                 ], bulletType='bullet', bulletFontSize= 5, bulletOffsetY= -2, leftIndent=10, start='circle'),
        ListItem(Paragraph(text2, styles["Normal"]))
        ], bulletType='1')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the top result for people searching for how to make nested lists in ReportLab, so I figured that I should relay the proper solution to this issue, which I discovered from an [old post on reportlab-users](https://groups.google.com/g/reportlab-users/c/bmbqSQ-Zmng).

The docs don't mention this at all, but you can give `ListFlowable` a `list` as one of its items. If that `list` contains a `Paragraph` and another `ListFlowable`, it will render the nested `ListFlowable` right after the `Paragraph`, *within the same bullet point*.

```
t = ListFlowable(
    [
        Paragraph("Item no. 1", style),
        [
            Paragraph("Item no. 2", style),
            ListFlowable(
                [
                    Paragraph("sublist item 1", style),
                    ListItem(Paragraph('sublist item 2', style), bulletColor='red')
                ],
                bulletType='bullet',
                bulletFontSize=5,
                start='square',
            )
        ],
        Paragraph("Item no. 3", style),
    ],
    bulletType='1',
    bulletFormat='%s.',
    bulletFontSize=8,
)
```

No faffing about with hiding the excess bullet, or telling ReportLab not to render it and then having to carefully manage the `value` of subsequent `ListItem`s. It just works exactly like `<ul>`s and `<ol>`s in HTML.

The above code renders like this:

[image: screenshot of results]

Answer (score 0):

So what I figured out now to solve that issue is to nest it againin another ListFlowable and set there the leftIndent to '0' and the bulletColor to 'white'.

```
lf = ListFlowable([ 
    ListFlowable([
    ListItem(Paragraph(text1, styles["Normal"]), spaceAfter=12), 
    ListFlowable([ListItem(Paragraph(text1a, styles["Normal"])), 
                ListItem(Paragraph(text1b, styles["Normal"])),t
             ], bulletType='bullet', bulletFontSize= 5, bulletOffsetY= -2, leftIndent=10, start='circle')], bulletColor='white', leftIndent=0),
    ListItem(Paragraph(text2, styles["Normal"]), spaceBefore=12),
    ], bulletType='1', bulletFontSize= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the numbering for one list item by inserting the nested list into ListItem with value argument set to 0:

ListFlowable([
Paragraph(...),
ListItem(ListFlowable(...nested list...), value=0)
ListItem(Paragraph(...), value=2) # to let the list go on
])

Comment: Be careful when doing this with bulleted lists. ReportLab will crash if you set `value=2` on a `ListItem` that's inside a Bulleted `ListFlowable`. You MUST use a string for `value` unless you use `0`, or ReportLab will crash. I went with `ListItem(para, value='•')` for my bulleted items that I actually wanted to have bullets, and ListItem(para, value=0) for those I didn't want bullets on.